# Visual Basics,Outlook Add-in ,Store Data in Local Storage

Tags: vb.net, outlook, local-storage, outlook-addin

I am making an Outlook Add-in (Visual Basics) in which the user needs to login first, this generates an access-token which is valid for 7 hours. 
I need to store this token for later use to verify.
Is there a way to create a local storage in Outlook itself?
Thanks in advance (Sharing is FUN!! :))

Answer (score 0):

There is a StorageItem object that you can create specifically for this purpose.  See here for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/storing-data-for-solutions